# Нужна помощь с библиотекой Telebot для Python Asked today Active today Viewed 2 times

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Я пишу Telegram-бота на Python с библиотекой **Telebot**, и у меня возникла проблема с написанием модуля, который должен решать математическое уравнение с 3-мя переменными, задаваемыми пользователем. Свой код прилагать не стану, ибо там совсем всё плохо. Был бы очень благодарен, если бы вы просто приложили ссылку на какой нибудь ресурс, где подобная проблема уже решается, ну или кусок кода если он у вас есть. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте с [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html)